# How can I make some stuff while fading the screen out and then to fade back in?

Tags: unity, c#

I want that when it's fading out and when the screen is black then do some stuff and then fade in back.

This is the FadeInOut script :

I have a problem with this script it does fade out and in but if I change the speed from 0.8f to 100f or to 0.01f the speed is almost the same. The fading duration is not changing.

I wanted to make that if I set the speed for example to 7f then the fade out and fade in overall will take 7 seconds.  So instead speed(fadeSpeed) to use duration and change something in the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FadeInOut : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region FIELDS
    public GameObject fadeOutUIGameobjectImage;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f;

    private Image fadeOutUIImage;

    public enum FadeDirection
    {
        In, //Alpha = 1
        Out // Alpha = 0
    }
    #endregion

    #region FADE
    public IEnumerator Fade(FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);

        float alpha = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 1 : 0;
        float fadeEndValue = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 0 : 1;
        if (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out)
        {
            while (alpha >= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }
            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);
            while (alpha <= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void SetColorImage(ref float alpha, FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        if (fadeOutUIImage == null)
        {
            fadeOutUIImage = fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.GetComponent<Image>();
        }

        fadeOutUIImage.color = new Color(fadeOutUIImage.color.r, fadeOutUIImage.color.g, fadeOutUIImage.color.b, alpha);
        alpha += Time.deltaTime * (1.0f / fadeSpeed) * ((fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? -1 : 1);
    }
}
```

The second script is how I'm using the fading now :

The problem in this script is that I want to make some stuff when the fade out is black when it's getting black make some stuff then fade in back. stuff I mean the part of code between the fade out and fade in :

```
StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.Out));

            navi.transform.parent = naviParent.transform;
            navi.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);//GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform.localPosition;
            navi.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);

            if (ikControl.target != null)
                ikControl.target.distance = 0;

            player.transform.LookAt(freeLookCam2.transform);

            freeLookCam2.enabled = true;

            StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.In));
```

And the full part :

```
private void Update()
    {
        ChangeChild();
    }

    public void ChangeChild()
    {
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, navi1.transform.position);
        if (dist < 0.1f && childChangedNaviIsHandChild == false)
        {
            childChangedNaviIsHandChild = true;
            ikControl.startMovingNAVI = false;

            StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.Out));

            navi.transform.parent = naviParent.transform;
            navi.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);//GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform.localPosition;
            navi.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);

            if (ikControl.target != null)
                ikControl.target.distance = 0;

            player.transform.LookAt(freeLookCam2.transform);

            freeLookCam2.enabled = true;

            StartCoroutine(fadeInOut.Fade(FadeInOut.FadeDirection.In));
        }

        if(dist < 0.3f && fadeOnce == false)
        {
            

            fadeOnce = true;
        }

        if (ikControl.startMovingNAVI)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, navi1.transform.position, 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting one coroutine, then you are doing a bunch of stuff and then you are starting another coroutine - all within the same Update. So all of that will happen immediately. The changes will happen immediately and then two coroutines will run simultaneously - one fading in and one fading out. When you want a 3 step process executed in sequence:

1. Fade to black
2. Do stuff
3. Fade back in

then all these things need to happen within one coroutine. This is how I would write this coroutine:

```
public IEnumerator Fade(float duration)
{
    // 1. fade to black
    fadeOutUIImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    for(float timePassed = 0f; timePassed < duration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime) {
        SetImageAlpha(timePassed / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

    // 2. do the stuff
    navi.transform.parent = naviParent.transform;
    navi.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);//GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform.localPosition;
    navi.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    navi.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    if (ikControl.target != null)
        ikControl.target.distance = 0;
    player.transform.LookAt(freeLookCam2.transform);
    freeLookCam2.enabled = true;

    // 3. fade back in
    for(float timePassed = 0f; timePassed < duration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime) {
        SetImageAlpha(1.0f - timePassed / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    fadeOutUIImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

private void SetImageAlpha(float alpha) {
    fadeOutUIImage.color = new Color(
        fadeOutUIImage.color.r,
        fadeOutUIImage.color.g,
        fadeOutUIImage.color.b,
        alpha
    );        
}
```

Comment: You can still put these in three coroutines, and then have a sequencing coroutine that says `yield return FadeToBlack(); yield return DoTheStuff(); yield return FadeBackIn();` to run each one to completion before starting the next. You could make `DoTheStuff` a delegate to have an execute around pattern you can re-use with different payloads in the middle of the sandwich. :)

Comment: What about using imageToFade.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, 0.3f, false); for the fading? Is that wrong to use it ? I saw in some solutions the suggestion is to use the CrossFadeAlpha. Just wondering.

Comment: @DanielLip The problem with that method is that there is no way to tell when the crossfade is finished. So you can not have those crossfades in form of a sequence in a coroutine.